# Swift - Automatic escape characters

Tags: xcode, escaping

Is there a way to automatically escape characters in Swift?

```
var myString = someMagicWord("#%"$@\/")
```

In c#, someMagicWord = @

In Android studio you can paste your weird string and the ide will automatically escape charecters for you.

Adding @zaph's example: There is a file with characters such as newline "\n", tab "\t", etc. Open the file, select all, copy, go to Xcode and paste inside a string statement such as @"pasted_code_here". The OP wants these characters escaped automatically to something like: @"\n\t"

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question

Comment: Example: There is a file with characters such as newline "\n", tab "\t", etc. Open the file, select all, copy, go to Xcode and paste inside a string statement such as @"pasted_code_here". The OP wants these characters escaped automatically to something like: @"\n\t".

Comment: Then the question should be probably tagged with `Xcode` since it has nothing to do with `ios` or `swift`...

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5 you can use raw strings, like so

```
var myString = #"#%"$@\/"#
```

Answer (score -1):

While in some languages this is doable (e.g.:python) in swift "escaping" those special characters  is not really possible because `newlines: \n`, `tablines : \t` etc are string literals. You can have a look here about that

[string literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID295)